# Neo4J - Is there a way to load multiple subqueries like LOAD ... CREATE .. LOAD .. CREATE .. LOAD ... in one Query (for testing)

Tags: mysql, csv, neo4j, cypher

So I'm trying to get one general database sheet for default. In MySQL, I can delete the whole database and run my code to generate the default database again. e.g. the only document for MySQL -> wwfsaew.sql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS wwfsaew;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wwfsaew;

CREATE TABLE Flughafen (...)
...
INSERT INTO Flughafen (...)
...
UPDATE Flughafen SET ...
...
CREATE VIEW ...
...
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
...
```

But the same in Neo4J doesn't work. I always get the Error message: "Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError"

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/ingredients.csv'
    AS a
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/users.csv'
    AS b FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
        LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/recipes.csv'
    AS c FIELDTERMINATOR ';'

CREATE (ing:ingredients{name:a.ingredientName,
    ingredientName:a.ingredientName})
CREATE (use:users{
    name:b.userName,
    userName:b.userName,
    userEmail:b.userEmail,
    userPassword:b.userPassword,
    enabled:b.enabled})
CREATE (rec:recipe{
    name:c.recipeName,
    recipeName:c.recipeName,
    prepTimeInMin: c.prepTimeInMin,
    restTimeInMinutes: c.restTimeInMinutes,
    prepText: c.prepText,
    people: c.people,
    viewCount: c.viewCount,
    difficultyName: c.difficultyName,
    mealTypeName: c.mealTimeName,
    createdByUser: c.createdByUser})
```

I don't have an idea why it doesn't work like this because every subquery for its own is ~20ms. I tried it with `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 250` but then it throws a Semantic Error because it is an explicit transaction instead of an implicit one.
So my question is: How can I get only one .cypher or.csv file to run it in Neo4J to get the default GraphDatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query throws an `OutOfMemoryError` because you are trying to import 3 csv together, and in this way the total number of rows will be the Cartesian product of the three CSVs.
That is, if you have 3 csv with 50 rows, you'll receive from the first `load csv` 50 results, for each result with the 2nd `load csv` 50 result, and for each result with the 3rd one 50 results.
Therefore you will have 50x50x50 result.
Try importing one csv at a time, with the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT NNN` in case, that is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/ingredients.csv'
    AS a
CREATE (ing:ingredients{name:a.ingredientName,
    ingredientName:a.ingredientName})
```

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/users.csv'
    AS b FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (use:users{
    name:b.userName,
    userName:b.userName,
    userEmail:b.userEmail,
    userPassword:b.userPassword,
    enabled:b.enabled})
```

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///C:/Users/Enes/CSV_import/recipes.csv'
    AS c FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (rec:recipe{
    name:c.recipeName,
    recipeName:c.recipeName,
    prepTimeInMin: c.prepTimeInMin,
    restTimeInMinutes: c.restTimeInMinutes,
    prepText: c.prepText,
    people: c.people,
    viewCount: c.viewCount,
    difficultyName: c.difficultyName,
    mealTypeName: c.mealTimeName,
    createdByUser: c.createdByUser})
```

---

EDIT:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 200
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///ingredients.csv'
    AS a
CREATE (ing:ingredients{name:a.ingredientName,
    ingredientName:a.ingredientName})

with 1 as ignored limit 1

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///users.csv'
    AS b FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (use:users{
    name:b.userName,
    userName:b.userName,
    userEmail:b.userEmail,
    userPassword:b.userPassword,
    enabled:b.enabled})

with 1 as ignored limit 1

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///recipes.csv'
    AS c FIELDTERMINATOR ';'

CREATE (rec:recipe{
    name:c.recipeName,
    recipeName:c.recipeName,
    prepTimeInMin: c.prepTimeInMin,
    restTimeInMinutes: c.restTimeInMinutes,
    prepText: c.prepText,
    people: c.people,
    viewCount: c.viewCount,
    difficultyName: c.difficultyName,
    mealTypeName: c.mealTimeName,
    createdByUser: c.createdByUser})

return 1 limit 1
```

Comment: So in between these LOAD commands, I should put ```USING PERIODIC COMMIT NNN```?
Like:
```LOAD CSV ... CREATE () .... USING PERIODIC COMMIT NNN LOAD CSV ... ```

Comment: My question is another because I want only one query for everything.

Comment: You should put your periodic commit before all, if you are on Neo4j Desktop or Browser, you should prepend :auto to your query. 
If you want to load all 3 csv in one query you have to add between one load and another some `with ....` . I edited my answer with the unique query, for all of 3

Comment: Thank you! Everything works as it should be :)